# make jquery only apply to single ahref on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I currently have some Jquery code that allows text to be added to a link depending on the h1 and h2 of the page.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ekso9qrm/)

The problem is now this is being applied to all a hrefs on the page including the menu etc, This is not helpful as these links do not need the extra added code.

Here is the code we are using

HTML:

```
<h1>Web Developer</h1>
<h2>jQuery</h2>
<a href="example.com/?Question12=">job link</a>
<hr>
<div id="href"></div>
```

Jquery

```
var link = $("a").attr("href");

link = link+$("h1").html()+"&Question11"+$("h2").html();

link = link.replace(/\s/g,"%20");

$('a').attr("href", link);

$("#href").html(link);
```

Comment: If you just want a single element, consider using an id. If you have multiple, but not all, then use a class.

Comment: You should give your element a nice id and use this to select your element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `id` attribute to the `<a...>` element so that you can refer to it explicitly.

HTML:

```
<a href="example.com/?Question12=" id="thisOne">job link</a>
```

jQuery

```
var link = $("a#thisOne").attr("href");
```

Comment: Hey i have just tried this but it still affected the other links maybe you could make a jsfiddle so i could see if im doing it correctly ? Thanks

Comment: sorry that was me being an idiot ive sorted it now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is select the anchor with information it already possesses:

For `<a href="example.com/?Question12=">job link</a>` use:

```
var link = $('a[href$="Question12="]').attr('href');
```

This uses jQuery's "[ends with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)" attribute selector.

[Attribute Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

The great thing about JavaScript and jQuery is that you rarely have to modify your markup to include them and use them effectively. "Unobtrusive JavaScript" builds on the principal of [Progressive Enhancement](http://alistapart.com/article/progressiveenhancementwithjavascript) which many developers have practiced for years.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Next Adjacent Selector](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) (“prev + next”) relying on your header element

```
$('h2+a').attr("href", link);
```

This will do the job for you if you don't want to mess with HTML identifiers